# Is this unarmored defense option balanced

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, armor-class

One of the conceits of a campaign I am running is that in some areas classes like the fighter or paladin would not rely on heavy armor.

Is the following option balanced?

> ##### Unarmored Warrior
>
> **Prerequisite:** Requires proficiency in Heavy Armor
>
> You no longer have armor proficiency.
>
> Choose Constitution, Wisdom, Intelligence, or Charisma. You may determine your AC using 10 + the chosen ability modifier + your Dexterity modifier. You may still benefit from a shield if you are proficient with it.

Note that this is not a feat, just a option that any character can choose to replace Heavy Armor Proficiency.

Comment: I’m going to assume you don’t mean for losing the prerequisite of the feature to stop the feature from working.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, correct. That was more to clarify that you need it to start with.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for omitting Strength as one of the options?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber, Strength and Dexterity seemed overpowered since you would be potentially increasing your ability to attack as well as defend, or gain double benefit for a single ability increase.

Comment: @StarHawk most would say that dex itself already does precisely this (for finesse and ranger weapons). I'd say that how valid this is depends on the presence of feats,  house rules and how big of a drawback having only access to piercing damage is. Ultimately it's outside the scope of your question, but maybe there are deeper considerations to be had beyond "is iit OP?"

Comment: What would happen if you multiclass to gain back armor proficiency? For instance, you start as a Fighter and take this option to lose all armor proficiency. Then somewhere down the road you multiclass into Cleric which gives back light and medium, and potentially heavy with the right domain?

Comment: @MivaScott, you cannot. The "you no longer have armor proficiency" is permanent.

Comment: @StarHawk, but "have" refers to current (and the past). But in the future,if take a level in, say, Cleric, _"When you gain a level in a class other than your first, you gain only some of that class's starting proficiencies. Armor: light armor, medium armor, shields"_ So you **gain** something new. If this is not the case, you will need to update your wording so that not only do you lose the armor proficiency, but you cannot gain them back in any way such as by feat, multiclassing, class feature, etc.

Comment: Piece of advice:  You can avoid the weird paradoxical recursion problems if, instead of "You no longer have armor proficiency.", you say "Instead of the normal benefits of armor proficiency, you receive no benefit at all".

Answer (score 7):

### You make the MAD, SAD

Simply put, by giving up Heavy Armor proficiency, the character no longer has to worry about a high Strength score. Instead they can focus on what would be their primary stat(s).

Consider a Hexblade Paladin: using this option, they no longer need invest large amounts in Strength. they can max out Charisma and Dexterity and achieve a comparable AC much quicker.

### I see this as a very dangerous change

Let's do some math, using the pont buy system to keep things level.

You're basic distribution of points would give you 15, 15, 12, 12, 9, 8 (or 15, 15, 12, 10, 10, 9). These numbers can be tweaked slightly based on racial bonuses, but I'll stick with non-altered values to start with.

Without this option, you'd need 15 Str, 15 Cha, Dex 12, Con 12, and Int/Wis with whatever you feel like.

This is not bad. But the only reason to have that high of a Strength is to wear armor. Strength checks and saving throws are not used that often, and you're using Charisma for attack/damage. This means an average Dexterity and Constitution, and low Intelligence and Wisdom. But that low Dex is going to hurt as lower initiative, lower Dexterity checks and saving throws (which happen often), and lower Stealth checks (which you'll have disadvantage on from Heavy Armor).

With this option you change it to 15 Cha, 15 Dex, 13 Str, 12 Con, and 8 for Int/Wis. The 13 is purely for multiclassing. Now you still have the high Charisma for attacks/damage/spell casting. You also get a high Dexterity for checks and saving throws. Because you're not wearing heavy armor, you no longer have disadvantage on Stealth checks and will have a better bonus.

So the change is minor, but only because of need for a 13 Strength for multiclassing. But there are plenty of other cases where that won't be an issue like certain Cleric Domains.

Now let's look at better examples...

Artificers, Rangers, and Druids all get Medium Armor proficiency. If you're a Human Variant, or a Custom Lineage, you get a free Feat at first level. Use that feat to get *Heavily Armored* for Heavy Armor proficiency (and +1 Strength which might help with getting that 13 required for multiclassing). Now give up armor proficiency via this option.

Druids and Rangers can now completely focus on Wisdom and Dexterity to quickly max out their core abilities. Artificers can also do this, especially the Battle Smith's as they use Int for their attacks and damage as well as spells.

### As for defense...

Using point buy, once you apply racial bonuses, you can easily get 16 in Dexterity and one of the other stats.

That means at level one your AC is 10 + 3 + 3 = 16. That is equal to the highest medium armor (breastplate = AC 14 + 2 for Dex).

By level 8, you could raise your primary stat twice to 20 making your minimum AC 10 + 3 + 5 = 18. That is equal to plate armor. While still being naked and not spending a single gold on armor. No disadvantage on Stealth, no way to "strip off" your AC, and not weighed down.

All the while, the character has maxed out their primary stat for better fighting, higher DC on their spells, and so on.

### Other perks...

- Aarakocra fighters can now use their flight feature since it doesn't work if wearing heavy (or medium) armor.
- Druids will have a decent AC since there are so few non-metal high AC armor options.
- People won't clank when using *disguise self* to look like a peasant.
- No more getting caught with your <strike>pants down</strike> armor off, when a battle breaks out while taking a long rest.

---

- MAD = Multiple Attribute Dependant; Requires a large number of attributes to be higher to make an "effective" build
- SAD = Single Attribute Dependant; Requires only one (or two) attributes to be higher to make an "effective" build

Comment: So you think it gives better AC than heavy armor or medium+2Dex? The later also doesn't require str investment. At a meaningful level I mean. Say, before lvl 15.

Comment: For context, I agree with yiur SAD point. But I'd like to see if it actually makes a difference.

Comment: @MivaScott, would it improve anything if I limited the stat choices?

Comment: @3C273, using point buy, you can easily get 16 in Dex and one other stat (say Cha). That means at level one your AC is 10 +3 + 3. Which is equal to the highest medium armor (breastplate = AC 14 + 2 for Dex). By level 8, you could raise your primary stat twice to 20 making your minimum AC 10 + 3 +5. That would be equal to plate armor. While still being naked and not spending a single gold on armor. No disadvantage on Stealth, no way to "strip off" your AC. Added this to the answer.

Comment: @StarHawk, how would you limit it that would make it worthwhile? You're basically taking a well-regarded feature of Barbarian and Monks and giving it away to everyone. Basically, players will only use that feature if it gives them an advantage, but when it gives an advantage, it potentially swings the balance very far. Allowing a character to base their AC on two stats is on the scale of offering them +2 plate armor (18 + 2 = 10 + 5 + 5).

Comment: I have very rarely seen a serious situation where being stripped off was a problem. Neither the 1.5k gold cost. But it's a free alternative to both of those things. Thanks for the added details. Enjoy the +1

Comment: @3C273, Hardly seems like a character unless they have been thrown in jail, a pit, or some other adventure where they start off without armor and weapons.

Comment: @StarHawk to repeat what miva said another way. Mental stats are pretty much equivalent in this case. You only limit which claster classes becomes very efficient for the cost of a 1lvl dip into fighter/paladin/other. And you cheapen a gimmick of two classes who usually can't abuse it.

Comment: And buffing half-casters actually. Palladin and ranger can now maxout their defense, offense and spells.

Comment: @3C273, that was actually going to be one of my examples; Human Ranger takes the _Heavily Armored_ feat to get heavy armor prof (And +1 to str). Now they give up heavy armor and max out Dex and Wisdom.

Comment: While this is spot on, the answer could be rounded out by mentioning the down side: losing all armor proficiency means no magic armor special abilities later on.

Comment: @JoelHarmon, I don't see that as a big deal. Cloaks, rings, boots can all have powers that don't require armor prof. Artificers can infuse robes with special features like protection and resistance.

Comment: You've got an error in your argument here: You claim the Hexblade/Paladin saves 9 point buy points by being able to dump Str if they don't need to wear heavy armor. But they can't actually dump it completely, as you're not allowed to multiclass to or from Paladin unless you have a Str of 13 (and Cha 13, but you want Cha for both classes anyway). So you can't save 9 points, just 4 (the incremental cost of going from 13 to 15 Str).

Comment: With that correction, you're not actually going from MAD to SAD; before, you needed either 13 Str and 14 Dex (for best medium armor AC) or 15 Str alone (for Plate). This just makes it *possible*, if you spend basically *all* your ASIs on ASIs instead of feats, to *barely* exceed the benefits of non-magical armor, but you end up more MAD than before, needing 13 Str, MAX Dex, MAX Cha, and still wanting good Con (because everyone does), vs. 15 Str, MAX Cha and good Con or 13 Str, 14 Dex, MAX Cha and good Con. This does de-MAD Fighters and Heavy Armor Clerics, but Hexadins gain little from it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I rewrote the opening math to better explain the advantages of this option for Hexblade/Paladin. Also added example of how other characters could benefit.

Answer (score 4):

#### If you didn’t allow a shield, it would *definitely* be balanced

Without magic, armored defense maxes out at 20, for plate armor and a shield. This option would max out at 22, because you can have Dex 20, (other score) 20, and a shield. So nixing the shield would put you squarely into the realm of established precedent that we would balance with.

There is a case to be made for the shield too; getting Dex 20 and (other score) 20 can be really burdensome, so for a lot of characters the full plate is a lot cheaper. And for that matter, the barbarian can already do this, since they are allowed shields. Is +2 AC, and side-benefits for Stealth and “in a prison without your gear” situations, appropriate for the cost of getting the appropriate ability scores all the way to 20? I think it might be, but this is a harder case to make. Ultimately, I’d probably just playtest it, if it were me. Try and see how problematic it is.

But the MAD/SAD thing isn’t nearly that big a deal. The single most problematic case is the paladin/hexblade, because that build can dump Strength and gets free heavy armor proficiency. Except they need Strength 13 to multiclass paladin, so they cannot dump it **that far**. At that point, the 14 necessary to achieve AC 19 with medium armor and a shield is a very small cost. Is AC 20 worth finding another 6 points for Dexterity? Or even if we allow the shield, and can go to 22? It’s not obvious to me that it’s worth it. Best case we’re still looking at 2 ASIs to get that Dex 20, and that’s after using 1 to get Cha 20. Those are big costs.

And **nothing** else has nearly so strong a case to make here. A Dexterity-based fighter, I guess? But then where do you go with the other ability score? Constitution, I guess; fighters like Constitution. But it’s not like multiclassing barbarian is *hard* for a fighter, so that’s not really a big deal. I guess a Dexterity-based single-classed paladin is also possible and a decent use-case. But “decent” isn’t “overpowered,” I think.

Anyway, without a shield, definitely not overpowered. With a shield, maybe questionable, but at the very least it’s not clearly imbalanced. As I said, I’d playtest it.

Comment: Nitpick : "Other unarmored defense options (barbarian, monk) don’t allow a shield at the same time" Barbarians can. But a barbarian with 20dex/20con is not standard. (Viable but not standard)

Comment: @3C273 I did not realize that! Should have double-checked. Then yeah, even more on board with that.